# Create custom popup menu in IOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I have an existing **IOS Objective C** project that is created using the old **xib** method and not the newer storyboard way.

I want to create custom popup menus similar to the snapchat popup when the user holds down a friends story like so:

[image]

How can I create a custom popup like this with custom size/shape and custom buttons on it?

Comment: I have a feeling that you haven't researched this at all, try Googling the title to your question

Comment: All good examples are in swift which im not using

Comment: add "objective-c" to the end of your search to get objective-c examples, there are tons of GitHub projects and tutorials for this, as well as a wide variety of ways that you can achieve what you want.  Do your research then post a specific question to explain why what you have tried isn't working.

Comment: Harry Boy In objective C you can do easily